# Can i use tags in mixin in pug?

Tags: pug

How i can use tag in variable in mixin in pug?

```
mixin crblock(img, title)
  figure.cr-block
    .cr-block--img
      img(src=img, alt="")
    figcaption.cr-block--caption= title

+crblock('img/carelist/z1.svg', 'Text <br> text')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you meant an HTML tag (`<br>` in this case) when you mentioned 'tag'.

For which, you need to use escaping in the PUG syntax. 
You may use the `!=` operator or the `!{}` operator for the same.

```
figcaption.cr-block--caption!= title
```

or

```
figcaption.cr-block--caption !{title}
```

Tested using http://naltatis.github.io/jade-syntax-docs/#escaping.

Hope this helps.